# getting sql statement behind view

Tags: c#, sql

I have a c# application (2008) that gets data from sql server (2005).
I have a view in sql server that prepares data for display, something like this (simplified):

```
select Places.Name as [Location], Parts.Name as [Part Name]
from  Places inner join Parts 
on Places.Id=Parts.Location
```

I have to filter this with "where" statement that is built in code and is like:

```
where (Places.Id=1 or Places.Id=15) and 
      (Parts.Id=56 or Parts.Id=8 or Parts.Id=32)
```

I can of course keep the basic select statement in my code, but i likw to have things defined only in one place :) and the question is if there is any way to get the select statement behind the view in sql server? Or to get the contents of stored procedure?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Information Schema View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181381.aspx), you may find your solution.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what i wanted! I will prepare a stored procedure that will bring the string and remove "create view .... as" from it.

Comment: +1. I keep forgetting the Information Schema's... I must be getting old.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information schema views as jani suggested is one option.

Another is using the sp_helptext system stored procedure. `sp_helptext YourView` or `sp_helptext YourStoredProcedure` gets you the entire object definition.

You can find more information about the at `sp_helptext` system stored procedure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stored procedure to execute your query (and combining your basic query string, with your where clause), you can accomplish this by using the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string selectCommand = "EXEC sp_YourStoredProcedure @whereClause";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@whereClause", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    command.Parameters["@whereClause"] = whereClause;
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.NextResult())
        {
            string location = reader.GetString(0);
            string partName = reader.GetString(1);

            // do something
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

**Edit:** Example of dynamic stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_YourStoredProcedure
(
    @whereClause NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = N'
    select Places.Name as [Location], Parts.Name as [Part Name] 
    from  Places inner join Parts  
    on Places.Id=Parts.Location '
    + @whereClause

     EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: how can i use as parameter part of sql statement?

Comment: You can execute dynamic sql by using sp_executesql (see example above).